# Use GoogleApiClient in Fragment and setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm in a **fragment** Like this:

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
   @Override View onCreateView(..){
      ...
      Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_layout);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MyGoogleClass.checkPlayServices(getContext(), getActivity())) {
               //here my problem
               MyGoogleClass.buildGoogleApiClient(getContext());
            }
         }
      });
   } 
}
```

And below I have the functions:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) { //do something }

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { //do some else}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { // log error }
```

Where **MyGoogleClass** has one function:

```
public static synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
     .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) context)
     .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) context)
     .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}
```

But my problem is that when I try to call function, with **"getContext()"** it return the error:

> MyActivity cannot be cast to
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks

I have tried with:

```
...
MyGoogleClass.buildGoogleApiClient(this);
...
```

But I can't compile my code because it return:

> error: incompatible types: MyFrag cannot be converted to Context

The problem is that the getContext is referred to **MyActivity** but so How can I create `new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)` in Fragment?

Comment: have you tried `this` instead?

Comment: Read the stacktrace carefully...
`MyActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks`

Seems like your method is expecting `GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks` interface and is getting a `MyActivity` instead of it.

Comment: Does your `MyActivity` implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` ?

Comment: Yes, I know that if I put the callback and interface in my acitivity it works because getContext() is referred to activity, but my Problem is that I need put the interface in Fragment (if is possible) .

I have tried with `this` but I can't compile because `<anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context` And i I try to put `Myfragment.this` but the error is the same

Comment: @LorenzoBerti yes, of course, you can implement the interface in your fragment. The problem is the error when you try using `this` instead. I have similiar issue before and I am already proposing what I did to fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here in your `buildGoogleApiClient()` method you try to cast the passed activity to `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`

> addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) context)

This on itself is not possible. According to the documentation this is an interface, and since Activity/Context object in your method is required, you have to implement it into your `MyActivity` and not your fragment.

---

Additionally, to ensure type encapsulation and strictness you could apply the following signature (for clarification, added the body, too):

```
public static synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(
                    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks conCallbacks,
                    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener conListener)
                                                throws IllegalArgumentException {

     Context context = null;
     if (conCallbacks instanceof Activity)
         context = conCallbacks;
     else if (conListener instanceof Activity)
         context = conListener;
     else
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
             .addConnectionCallbacks(conCallbacks)
             .addOnConnectionFailedListener(conListener)
             .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}
```

Now you could call it simply by

```
MyGoogleClass.buildGoogleApiClient(getActivity(), getActivity());
```

OR e.g. if the `OnConnectionFailedListener` is implemented by the Fragment

```
MyGoogleClass.buildGoogleApiClient(getActivity(), this);
```

With that you get:

- At least one of you interfaces is implemented by an activity, thus reuse the object.
- Apply separation of concerns principle.
- Single responsibility principle is now also applicable.
- Cleaner and more concise code.
- Greater flexibility (any of the two can be implemented in standalone object, e.g. in the Fragment).